# Audio won't autoplay

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="Rick Roll.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it won't play automatically. Is it because the file is too big?

Answer (score 1):

Media like video or audio will not play automatically anymore. This is a security thing. In order to play the media, user must interact with the page, like with a click.

Comment: Technically, there are other conditions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability

Answer (score 0):

That is because non muted autoplayed media are blocked by browsers. Here is what MDN says about it:

> As a general rule, you can assume that media will be allowed to autoplay only if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
> - The user has interacted with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
> - If the site has been allowlisted; this may happen either automatically if the browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or manually through preferences or other user interface features
> - If the autoplay feature policy is used to grant autoplay support to an  and its document.

Add the `muted` like so:

```html
<audio controls autoplay muted>
  <source src="Rick Roll.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your `src` that is invalid.

```
<source src="Rick Roll.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Try for fix that(if is this):

```
<source src="RickRoll.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The file might very well have a space in it. If that's the case, this would still not point to the right file.